# Problemas con combo-box que manda jsp de cierre de sesion

Tags: java, jquery, spring

queria ver si podrian ayudarme, lo que pasa es que no quiero que se redireccione al combobox cuando la sesion hayase terminado sino que ese de "Ups Ha ocurrido un problema etc..." lo pinte en toda la pantalla, alguna manera de poderlo hacer el tiempo lo tengo en 1 minuto y este es el codigo que tengo que se encarga de que un cierto tiempo la sesion finalice,

1// en el XML

Espero y puedan brindarme alguna idea de como podria corregir este problema

Saludos a todos cordiales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este metodo es el que hace la consulta en el controller y lo returna en un .jsp llamado error, y ese mismo se pinta en el combo-box y que no deseo que se muestre de esa manera

```
@RequestMapping({"/obtieneGrupos.do"}) public String obtieneGrupos(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute AmbienteTO ambienteIN, @ModelAttribute GuiaTO guiaIN, ModelMap modelMap) { 
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); if(session == null || session.getAttribute("usuarioTO") == null){
ExceptionTO mensajeErrorTO = new ExceptionTO(); mensajeErrorTO.setMensaje("La sesión ha terminado. Vuelva ingresar al sistema por favor");

        modelMap.addAttribute("mensajeErrorTO", mensajeErrorTO);
        return "comunes/error";             
    }
```

Esta es la vista, y es usada una funcion que de esa misma la manda a llamar:

```
function seleccionaGuia(valor) { realizaPost('./obtieneGrupos.do', '#recordsFrm', '#cargaGrupos', 'cargaGrupos'); }
```

Esto es una funcion generica que hace que hace que cargue la informacion que previamente aparece un Spinner:

```
function realizaPost(url, idForm, divResult, idLoadingTarget) {

var spinner = loading(idLoadingTarget);
if(idForm != null) {

    $.post(url, $(idForm).serialize(), function(data){

        //alert(data.indexOf("La sesión ha terminado"));
// if(data.indexOf("La sesión ha terminado") != -1) { //
// $("#divPrincipal").empty().append(data); //
// } else {

            //SUCCESS
             $(divResult).empty().append(data);
             stopLoading(spinner);

        //}

    }).fail(function() {
        //FAIL

    });


} else {
    $.post(url, function(data){         
        $(divResult).empty().append(data);
        stopLoading(spinner);
    });
}
}
```

Me dices si necesitas otra que pueda proporcionar y con gusto lo pongo... Saludos

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el codigo revelante para que te podamos ayudar, principalmente en tu vista, que supongo recuperas via ajax algun dato

Comment: Este es el metodo que realiza la busqueda en el controller y en el return error es un .jsp que se redirecciona a ese combo-box

Comment: A cabo de agregar el codigo en los comentarios ya que por aqui no puedo saludos

Comment: La parte de comentarios es para cosas muy sencillas, para agregar codigo y fotos simpre se debe de editar la pregunta como te comento el amigo @x4mp73r

Comment: Listo amigos ya volvi a editar mi post con todo y codigo :)

Comment: Muy bien lo que pasa aqui es que tu no estas arrojando ningun estatus de error, la petición pasa como si fuera un comportamiento normal, lo que necesitas es mandar un codigo de error para que lo puedas cachar en tu javascript, de hecho se ve que lo intentaste como `if ( data.indexOf("La sesión ha terminado") != -1` Podrias ir checando este tema en [este link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Hola de nuevo, estoy revisando los post del link que me pasaste pero no logro comprender mucho, soy nuevo en esto mas o menos podrias guiarme en base al codigo que puse, ya sobre la marcha lo ire solucionando, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto fue como solucione el problema, espero y a muchos les sirva, Saludos 
            //Esta validacion sirve para que el resultado no se pinte en donde se muestra el Spinner, Es decir, que se muestre en toda la pantalla
            //y pinte el resultado en el divPrincipal

```
        if(data.indexOf("n ha terminado") != -1) {
            $("#divPrincipal").empty().append(data);
            stopLoading(spinner);

        } else {

            //SUCCESS
             $(divResult).empty().append(data);
             stopLoading(spinner);

        }
```

El programa no encontraba esta cadena "n ha terminado" Solo se borro lo que estaba antes de la "n"